# How to read icons from .exe and .dlls in C++/Qt (on windows)?

Tags: windows, qt, dll, icons, exe

How can I read the icons from a DLL or an EXE file, using C++ (and Qt) ?

I can't find anything relevant on google, I only get how to change application icon using qt, which is not what I need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand what you're trying to do, this should be possible through the general [`LoadResource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648046%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function or the specific [`LoadIcon`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648072%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function. An example of the former can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648008%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#_win32_Updating_Resources).

You would create a handle to the exe or DLL using [`LoadLibrary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which you subsequently use as an argument in the `LoadResource` or `LoadIcon` function.

I don't know of any Qt functions providing similar options, but perhaps others do.

Comment: Thank you, I have one more question... what is the format that the icon is in? A plain .ico file in memory?

Comment: I'm not sure from the top of my mind, but I would assume it is similar. Or at least in the form of a structure with similar fields. But you might want to look it up.